# CSS - How to create a bg image over 100% with content below window

Tags: html, image, css

I am hoping one of you can help. I have a problem that with googling and checking the forums I have not been able to solve.

I would like to create a landing page that has a tall bg image that extends to 100% width and adjusts to the browser window + the dynamic height of the content. All the content should be below the boundary of the browser window so its just the image that can be seen when the browser first loads up and you scroll down to the content which sits over the bottom part of the extended image.

My HTML currently is:

```
<body>
    <section id="sectionOne">
        <div id="sectionOneLanding"></div>
        <div id="sectionOneContent">CONTENT TO SIT HERE</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

And my CSS is currently:

```
html,
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#sectionOne {
    height:100%;
    background-image: url(../images/cliff.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

#sectionOneLanding {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

At the moment, the image crops to 100% browser height and when you scroll down the additional content sits over a white bg instead of the remainder of the image. I believe this is due to the #sectionOne height being 100% but when I set it to higher than 100% it pushes my content further down but still on a white bg. Changing Background-Size to 100% also didn't work. It reacted the same as using cover.

Any ideas? Is there a handy CSS trick?

Apologies if this doesn't make clear sense. Ask any questions you need to as its hard to describe.

Comment: See [Creating a fullscreen hero DIV for your site header](http://www.web2feel.com/creating-a-fullscreen-hero-div-for-your-site-header/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much. Can you put this into an answer below so that I can approve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use positioning for this case.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#sectionOne {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/cliff.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #99f;
}

#sectionOneLanding {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="sectionOne">
  <div id="sectionOneLanding"></div>
  <div id="sectionOneContent">CONTENT TO SIT HERE</div>
</section>
```

You don't need `width: 100%`. But you need `margin: 0;` as there are default margins. I have added a background colour so that you can clearly see the background spanning fully leaving the content in the next page.

If you need both the image and the content to be in the same page, the you need to use Flex Box.

**FlexBox Example**

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#sectionOne {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
#sectionOneLanding {
  background-color: #99f;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section id="sectionOne">
  <div id="sectionOneLanding"></div>
  <div id="sectionOneContent">CONTENT TO SIT HERE</div>
</section>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview image]

Comment: how do you make the purple behind the content thats below it?

Comment: @EamonYates Which purple? I used background colour.